# elementType prop type validation default value

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I wonder what would be the default prop type value for `elementType` prop validation. I just want to render nothing if no component is passed.

```
PrivateRoute.defaultProps = {
  component: ???,
};

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  component: elementType,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put null as react will overlook it.

Comment: @Shota react being a library and when we say 'library' it means someone done tremendous job to wrap number of lines with some sane logic to do a common job. But behind the scene they rely on the initial ingredients of language, in this case JS and this is what makes react more powerful and flexible to simply let people use plain JS stuff. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrivateRoute.defaultProps = {
  component: null
};

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  component: elementType
};
```

This way you won't have any warning or error.